# Growl is not show me after delete

Tags: jsf, primefaces, growl

My purpose is to show an alert after a delete :
So my .xhmtl code is:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
        <h:form id="form">
    ....
        <p:growl autoUpdate="true" id="message" for="message" showDetail="true"/>
        </h:form>
```

and in my bean after delete I do:

```
         FacesMessage infoMsg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "DELETE", "DELETE OK" );
         FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("form:message", infoMsg);
```

The problem is the object is deleted correctly but the alert is not show. Anyone can help  me?

Comment: This does not look like a [mcve]

Comment: @Kukeltje I'm using it from delete now! I don't understand why it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

In [Primefaces 7 Documentation](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/7_0/#/components/growl) `growl` does not have `autoupdate`.

So you are using a different version.

I give you some sample code in case that you want to delete an item in a `datatable`

```
<h:form id="form">
            <p:growl id="msgs1" showDetail="true" life="3000"/>

          .....                       

                   <p:dataTable  value="#{ManageBean.dataList}" 
                             var="record" 
                             widgetVar="rolesTable" 
                             rowKey="#{record}">
                    <p:column headerText="Data" sortBy="#{record.desc }"
                        <h:outputText value="#{record.desc}"/>
                    </p:column>


                    <p:column headerText="Actions" width="100">
                        <p:commandLink

                                update="form" action="#{ManageBean.delete(record)}"
                                >
                            <h:graphicImage name="/icons/delete.png"
                                            title="Delete"/>
                        </p:commandLink>

                </p:dataTable>
```

And the code in ManageBean

```
 public void delete(ObjectType object) {

    //Your code for delete
    db.dbTransactions.deleteObject(object);

        //Create the message
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Successful Delete");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);

        //Remove the object from your list
        dataList.remove(object);
    }
}
```

Comment: That is assuming OP is using PF 7.. PF versions before did, so this answer is not applicable here.

Comment: https://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_6_2.pdf#256

Comment: Please let the other to judge if you strict or not. Maybe we are not so good as you but we try to learn and help others. So let us help and learn otherwise you will be the only person that will answer all the questions.

Comment: I'm not strict, I'm for good, clear, usefull answers. And after your edit, you have 2 questions in it. Questions about questions should be in comments. And look at the other answer, poster there states that growls should be in a different form, while you don't have this (and I agree, it should not be needed in general), so that is confusing to others. And I'm sure your solution works, but what is wrong in the question? Explicitiy addressing that is what makes an answer userfull.

Comment: And I appreciate the help, and I even provide feedback on the answer... to help getting good answers, to help that the person who answers can give better answesrs in the future etc... I could also just downvote if an answer is not 'good'  (yes I can a little more easy judge that because I have a decent amount of JSF and PrimeFaces knowledge. I know removed the downvote since this answer is no longer 'bad', but I did not upvote either since it is not 'good' either... Thanks for trying to help

Comment: And I downvoted the question too for two reasons http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/ and http://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive (to the answers)

Comment: @Kukeltje Thanks a lot !! All we are trying to learn and be better.

Answer (score 0):

Place growl component in own form like this.

```
     <h:form id="growlForm">
        <p:growl showDetail="true" life="8000" keepAlive="true"/>
    </h:form>
```

And create a message like this

```
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Success!", "Deleted"));
    PrimeFaces.current().ajax().update("growlForm");
```

Instead of using

```
PrimeFaces.current().ajax().update("growlForm");
```

You can also update the form by referencing it from the update attribute in your p:commandButton component. Also, your Bean which handels the request should not be RequestScoped, but ViewScoped.

Comment: **why** does this solve op's unclear problem (no [mcve] and it works for 'add')

Comment: @Kukeltje **Because** it shows a working implementation for what he's trying to do.

Comment: In many places I use a growl not in its own form and with an auto update, similar to the question. So what is wrong in the question then that you suggest to put it in its own form and not use autoupdate?  Answering that really helps.

Comment: Btw, I do appreciate the attempts to help!